# Xstream class within class

Tags: java, xml, xstream

In Xstream can we use this:

```
class Cat {
  int age;
  String name;
  Cat anotherSmallCat;
}
```

XML is

```
<cat><age>2</age><name>tom</name><cat><name>tommy</name></cat></cat>
```

I tried but getting exception.

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
```

Comment: You tried what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate your Cat as as below using `@XStreamAlias`,

```
@XStreamAlias("Cat")
public class Cat {

    int age;
    String name;

    @XStreamAlias("Cat")
    Cat anotherSmallCat;

}
```

Try to deserialize as below,

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.processAnnotations(Cat.class);
Cat cat = (Cat) xstream.fromXML(new File("test.xml"));
```

Don't forget to use [processAnnotations](http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream.html#processAnnotations%28java.lang.Class%29) method.